# kp theory of QW band structures in envelope function approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electronic-band-theory

I am currently trying to calculate wave functions and energy dispersions for quantum well heterostructures. The [kp method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C2%B7p_perturbation_theory) is my choice to do that. I already calculated band structures for bulk materials using an $8\times 8$ Hamiltonian (see [this page](http://www.optronicsdesign.com/en/theory/hamiltonian.php) or [this paper](http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.55.6960) for example). Here, the diagonal terms include the bulk band edges, which may be modified by strain. If I want to obtain the Hamiltonian within the envelope function approximation (EFA) to get the band structure for quantum wells (QWs), [this paper](http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.48.8918) (equivalently [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0039602894909040)) states that the replacement $k_z \to -\mathrm{i}\partial_z$ must be done as well as adding the built-in or external potential to the diagonal of the bulk Hamiltonian. My first question:

1) What is meant by built-in potential? Do they mean the additional energy coming from an electron being confined within the potential build by the bulk band edges? That means one has to solve Schrödingers Equation for a particle in a box (which is given by the bulk band edges) first to obtain the confinement energies, and then one could solve the Hamiltonian (iteratively, since it is a shooting problem because of the boundary conditions).

If the answer is "yes, you're right" to this question, heres a second one:

2) How is the Hamiltonian build within the method that the authors of the two last papers develop a method therein? What I understand from the paper is to replace different power of $k_z$ by a specific term. Also all position dependent variables have to be replaced by their Fourier transform. The bulk Hamiltonian already contains the confinement potential (or bulk band edges) so I do not have to add it to the diagonal, or do I? Wouldn't I also have to add a $dk'$ to all elements?

I appreciate any helpful comments.